# Referencing same svg with url

Tags: svg, mask

I'm adding a mask to a svg. In all the examples I've seen (for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)) they proceed by setting an id and then referencing with url

```
<svg>
    <mask id="some-id">...</mask>
    <g mask="url(#some-id)">...</g>

</svg>
```

That works fine for a couple svgs but it creates a lot of overhead because the ids must be unique. For example if I do

```
<!-- first svg!-->
<svg>
    <mask id="some-id">...</mask>
    <g mask="url(#some-id)">...</g>

</svg>
<!-- second svg!-->
<svg>
    <mask id="some-id">...</mask>
    <g mask="url(#some-id)">...</g>

</svg>
```

The first svg will get the second mask. Of course the problem is that ids should be unique, so my question is if there is some way to access the root svg. Then I could do something like:

```
<svg>
    <mask class="mask-class">...</mask>
    <g mask="url(svg/some-class)">...</g>

</svg>
```

In my case I'm creating the svgs dynamically with a library so it is much more preferable that it only knows its internal state.

Comment: No, it's not possible. And without unique IDs, your markup will be invalid. This is likely to lead to other problems. Why is it so difficult to provide unique ID values?

Comment: Would it be possible to define the SVGs in separate files and include them via an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @ccprog In my case I'm creating the svgs dynamically with a library so it is not possible. I've updated the question to reflect that

Comment: if you are using a library per-svg consider using an incrementing number (mask-1 mask-2 etc) or a guid as the id, so they are guaranteed unique